# Conflict in absolute import from constants

Tags: typescript, node-modules, eslintrc

I'm getting a conflict in my React project from an absolute import.

I have this line:

```
import { MY_CONSTANT } from 'constants';
```

However, tsconfig thinks that the constants folder is coming from `node_modules` instead of `src/` where I have my own `constants` file defined.

I have read about [tsconfig paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) and my `.eslintrc` in my root dir looks like this:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "commonjs": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "no-relative-import-paths"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "project": [
      "server/tsconfig.json",
      "client/tsconfig.json"
    ]
      },
      "node": {
        "moduleDirectory": [
          "client/src/",
          "client/node_modules",
          "server/src",
          "server/node_modules"
      ],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
```

My folder structure looks like:

```
repo/
  .eslintrc
  client/
  server/
```

When I click into definition of the `constants` file, I see it referencing this file:
`client/node_modules/@types/node/constants.d.ts` which I don't want. What can I do to fix my .eslintrc specification?

Comment: What's wrong with using `./constants`?

Comment: @caTS the `constants` file does not live in the same folder. It lives closer to the root directory.

So like:

```
repo/ 
  client/
    constants.ts
    feature/
      components/
        targetFile.tsx
```

and `targetFile` would be where I want to import `constants`